# Curb damage to my rim. Is this unsafe?

Tags: wheels, damage

I just noticed this damage to my wheel rim. The damage appears to be more light gouges than just scratches. Is this something I should get looked at, or is it just cosmetic? Thanks[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jLQ2D.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I think this damage, colloquially called "curb rash," is merely cosmetic. I would feel comfortable continuing to use the wheel. You could use some sandpaper and silver paint to neaten it up, but that isn't necessary.

Answer (score 1):

It is purely cosmetic. There is plenty of safety margin in all rims. The only worry is that the damage would act as a stress riser, but that mainly applies to rims that are used near their limit, like bicycle rims. Car rims have a huge safety margin, so there is nothing to worry about.

What you should investigate carefully is damage on the tire. Tire sidewall damage is a cause for concern. I don't see such damage in your case.

You were fortunate that you didn't damage your tire sidewall.